# Starting a thread closes my android application

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sleep, runnable

I want my thread to create delays of equal time and generate a toast after each time block. I tried the following code but it closes my application as soon  as I press the button:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "hiiiiiiiiiiiiiii", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    sleep(5000);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "hiiiiiiiiiiiiiii", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    sleep(5000);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "hiiiiiiiiiiiiiii", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }.start();
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is you can not access Ui element in a non-Ui thread. So you must be getting a Runtime exception. You can use runOnUi() or a Handler to do it on Main Thread  . Where runOnUi() is a method of Activity class and A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects associated with a thread's MessageQueue.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this,"Message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Or you can Use Handler

```
 new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this,"Message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Just make sure that when you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it. So you must not create it inside non Ui thread .

Answer (score 0):

You are creating another thread in your UI or main thread so can not print  or update UI here so you need to print toast message in UI thread like following way inside in your thread,

```
ActivityMain.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this,"Message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
//ActivityMain is the name of activity in which you are working
```